# fetching a select with joint tables, while loop requires an array otherwise nothing gets fetched

Tags: php

I have a method below, that selects some comments. I'm having issues getting the data, not because the query doesn't work but the while loop doesn't fetch the data if I don't use an array, here is my code

public function selectAllComment($idarticle)
    {
        $db = $this->getBdd();

```
    $sql = $db->query('SELECT c.comment, c.date_comment 
                                      FROM comments as c 
                                      INNER JOIN joint_a_comments on joint_a_comments.id_comment = c.id
                                      INNER JOIN articles a ON joint_a_comments.id_article = a.id
                                      WHERE a.id ="'.$idarticle.'"
                                      ORDER BY c.date_comment DESC 
                                      LIMIT 0,10');

    while($result[] = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $rescomment[] = new Comments($result);
    }

    return $rescomment;
```

With this above, I can see that the data are fetched using var_dump on $result.
However, first problem is:
**1- if I do the same with the object i.e. $rescomment (I instantiate a class to hydrate the data and I use them in a view...).
2- If I remove the brackets [] from $result, I get "boolean false"....any idea guys?**

Comment: First, refer to [PDOStatement::fetch documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) and check the fetch_style section.

Comment: Second, read up on prepared statements and parameterized queries.

Comment: Sorry I didn't come back to this issue, I was busy with something else. I checked the doc and still don't understand why one work but not the other... the while loop without an array doesn't work...